# Update wp option on change

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to update a checkbox on change in wordpress.

```
function update_value() {
    <?php update_option( 'value_to_change', get_option("value_to_change")); ?>
}
```

I'm calling this from a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return update_value()"name="value_to_change" value="1" <?php checked("1", get_option('value_to_change')); ?>" />
```

However, the value is not changed.

The goal is to store some new values in the database before I run some actions that needs to be based on the new data.

Comment: want to change checkbox value?

Comment: Yes, and for it to be stored before another action is run.